# Insert a character in a position if the text contains

Tags: powerquery

So how do you insert a value like double quotes in a specific position if the column contains 16.0, 15.0 and so on? And is there a way where I can check and ignore if there is already a double quote in that position?

I have tried with this code but I get an error if I try it

`#"Insert double quote" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Remove unwanted charachter", [Screen],  each if Text.Contains([Screen], "16.0") then Text.Insert(_, 5,"""") else if Text.Contains([Screen], "15.0") then Text.Insert(_, 5,"""") else if Text.Contains([Screen], "14.0") then Text.Insert(_, 5,"""") else [Screen] , type text)`

Comment: Where is your sample data and expected output?

Comment: My table has column is called screen and contains values like  15.6 UHD AG LED,  27Inch FHD (1920 x 1080) ,  16.0 WUXGA AG LED. I want to add a double quote after every 16.0 and 15.6, so that it is 15.0" and 16.0" but not the 27Inch FHD (1920 x 1080)  or any where inch is a part of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#"Replace" = Table.TransformColumns("#NameofYourPriorStepGoesHere",{{"Screen", each if Text.Contains(_,"Inch",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then _ else Text.Replace(Text.Replace(_,"15.0","15.0"""),"16.0","16.0"""), type text}})
```

Comment: I didn't work. I have double checked and try it with some other column name but i get this Expression.Error: The column 'Screen' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Screen.

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. You're really great at power query.

Comment: Nice +, but you are implicitly telling OP to nest multiple Text.Replace() function to cover all potential inches, right?

Comment: Yes, but there was only two, otherwise I could have regex'ed a xx.x number

Comment: which you seem to have done. nice

Answer (score 2):

> *"I want to add a double quote after every 16.0 and 15.6...."*

I'm assuming you may have text that would contain multiple inch representing figures. If that's the case, maybe a regular expression could be a good alternative here. In my example below I created a custom function called 'fnRegexReplace' which refers to:

```
(x,y,z)=>
let 
   Source = Web.Page(
                     "<script>var x="&"'"&x&"'"&";var z="&"'"&z&
                     "'"&";var y=new RegExp('"&y&"','gi');
                     var b=x.replace(y,z);document.write(b);</script>")
                     [Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
in 
   Source
```

I then created a new column invoking this function to showcase how it works:

[image]

[image]

The expression used is `\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?! x |\\))(?:"|inch)?(?:\\b|$)` and would to standardize the data a little bit better I opted to remove the word 'inch' where applicable and replace it with the double quote.